# Temporary object not destroyed correctly?

Tags: c++, memory-management, temporary-objects

See this code here:

```
class test
{
    int n;
    int *j;
public:
    test(int m)
    {
        n = 12;
        j = new int; 
        cin >> *j;
    }

    void show()
    {
        cout << n << ' ' << *j << endl;
    }

    ~test()
    {
        delete j;
    }

};

int main()
{
    test var = 123;
    var.show();
    return 0;
}
```

In this program compiler should complain about double deleting of `j`. First delete is done when temporary object `temporary(123)` is destroyed. The second delete is done when `var` object is destroyed. But this is working fine?

*Does it mean temporary object does not call destructor?*

Comment: 10001001058: You owe me one internets for indenting that code.

Comment: Add print statements to constructor/copy constructor/assignment operator/destructor to see when each is being called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The contentious line is this:

```
test var = 123;
```

The relevant standard text (that the pundits in the comments are referencing), I believe, is (8.5, "Declarators"):

> The function selected is called with the initializer expression as its argument; if the function is a constructor, the call initializes a temporary of the cv-unqualiﬁed version of the destination type. The temporary is an rvalue. The result of the call (which is the temporary for the constructor case) is then used to direct-initialize, according to the rules above, the object that is the destination of the copy-initialization. In certain cases, **an implementation is permitted to eliminate the copying inherent in this direct-initialization by constructing the intermediate result directly into the object being initialized**;

Indeed, in 12.6, we get an example of this:

```
complex f = 3;  // construct complex(3) using
                // complex(double)
                // copy it into f
```

Thus, in your use of `=`, your implementation is *probably* directly constructing object and eliminating the intermediate temporary entirely (and, as the comments have noted, most do).

This class doesn't copy properly, so creating a copy of it (and the freeing the copy and the original) would result in a double delete (and crashes, undefined behavior, etc.). Because no copies are created, this scenario does not happen above.

Comment: This is wrong. The letter of the standard says that a temporary is created and copied over to the final object. However, compilers are allowed to elide the copy (they can do that in other circumstances as well). All compilers I know of will elide the copy, but the copy constructor must still be accessible.

Comment: @avakar And because there is potentially a temporary which is destructed, the code has undefined behavior.  Even if there is no double delete in the code generated by his compiler.  The answer given is, as you say, wrong.

Comment: I can get this code to crash by compiling with `-fno-elide-constructors` on gcc.

Comment: @avakar: You are correct: I will edit the answer shortly. I had always thought this was standard. (Took forever to find the relevant text.)

Comment: @all: Edited. Thanks for the fact-checking.

Comment: @avakar will you please broaden your answer??

Comment: @10001001058: avakar is noting that the information contained in my original answer was incorrect. The answer has been corrected and expanded: is there something in particular you are looking for?

Comment: @thanatos i got you .is there any way to find when compiler is going to do copy elision or is it undefined ?

Comment: @10001001058: Typically, it shouldn't matter to you: the objects copy c-tor should create a valid copy. (You can make it private to prevent mishaps for non-copyable objects.) If you don't want the copy behavior, don't use the `=` syntax, use `test var(123);`, which will just call the appropriate c-tor.

Answer (score 2):

Two points: first, in this particular case, the compiler is allowed to
optimize out the temporary, by an explicit authorization of the
standard.  All of the compilers I'm familiar with do.  You can verify
whether this is happening in your code by defining a copy constructor
and instrumenting it.

Second is that if the temporary isn't optimized out, your code has
undefined behavior.  A double delete can have any imaginable behavior:
an immediate crash, corruption of the free space arena (leading to a
much later crash if the program continues running), no effect what so
ever, or anything else.  The fact that you are not seeing any symptoms 
doesn't mean that the code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the code happens to not blow up does not mean that it is correct.

Your class is buggy in that it is susceptible to double `deletes` in the manner you describe.

For example, changing `var.show();` to the following:

```
    test(var).show();
```

makes the code reliably blow up on my computer.

To fix, implement the copy constructor and the assignment operator.